# Saving image fails without error in django model form

Tags: django, django-models, image-uploading

I want to try to save an image to my model:

```html
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
class Leverandor(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    UserID = models.ForeignKey('Stamdata', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=200)
    URL = models.URLField('URL', max_length=200)
    ImageURL = models.ImageField('ImageURL',blank=True, null=True, upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

To this Form.py:

```html
class EditLeverandorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}))
    URL = forms.URLField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}))
    ImageURL = forms.ImageField
    class Meta:
        model = Leverandor
        labels = {
            'Name' : 'Leverandør',
            'URL' : 'Webside',
            'ImageURL' : 'Logo',
            }
        fields = ['UserID', 'Name', 'URL', 'ImageURL']
```

And rendererd to this view.py

```html
def add_leverandorer(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print (user_id)
        form = EditLeverandorForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/backend/leverandorer')
                
    else:
        print ('somethin goes wrong')
        print (user_id)
        form = EditLeverandorForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'backend/add_leverandorer.html', 
        {
            'title':'WestcoastShop - Backend',
            'form':  form,
        }
    )
```

The problem is that before I add the  instance=request.user part its saves the entry correct but without image. Now I add the part from Django documentation like provided for save to an variable path but nothing happened after i click to save button.

```html
<form action="/backend/leverandorer/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="simpleinput">Leverandør</label>
                                        {{ form.Name }}
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="simpleinput">Webside</label>
                                        {{ form.URL }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="simpleinput">Logo</label>
                                        {{ form.ImageURL }}
                                        <!--<input type="file" name="ImageURL" accept="image/*" required="" id="id_ImageURL" class="form-control-file">-->
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="UserID" name="UserID" value="{{ user.id }}">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Gem</button>
                                </form>
```

I didnt see an error but now its not saving the form in models also if ImageField is empty.

regards
Christopher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I I change the function in models.py to:

```html
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.UserID, filename)
class Leverandor(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    UserID = models.ForeignKey('Stamdata', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=200)
    URL = models.URLField('URL', max_length=200)
    ImageURL = models.ImageField('ImageURL',blank=True, null=True, upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

its works, but the Path is Username and not user.id

Comment: Fixed it by myself, the return string was mapped to Comapny name and not to userid

Answer (score 0):

You are using `UserID` as a hidden field. The hidden field will not pass the form-validation. So your following code will be false.

```
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/backend/leverandorer')
```

One of the solutions is, remove the `UserID` field from your template and update your view as follows.

```
  if form.is_valid():
     user_form = form.save(commit=False)
     user_form.UserID = request.user
     user_form.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it works before I add the Image Model to the form: 
+----+--------------+----------------------+----------+-----------+
| ID | Name         | URL                  | ImageURL | UserID_id |
+----+--------------+----------------------+----------+-----------+
| 20 | Apple DK     | https://apple.dk     |          |         1 |
| 23 | Microsoft DK | https://microsoft.dk |          |         1 |

Comment: Welcome! I think your form is not being validated. So, make sure that your form is correctly being validated.

Comment: I added now  {{ form }} and not single fields, and got same problem, no error but no savings.

Comment: It will be the same. It is not the issue.  Add `print(form.errors)` and you will see the error in the terminal.

Comment: I removed the part where the user_directory will be build and it worked: 

| 39 | Westcoast    | https://apple.dk             | foo/adsolute_banner3.png |         1 |
it has something todo with the function:

def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)